# Is the Reactjs team avoiding implementing its own redux-like state management?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm curious as to why the react team does not have its own redux-like state management system. Hooks, yes they do open up new use-cases and solve lots of problems but these feel more like Band-Aids and the major elephant in the room is still seems unaddressed. Since any app that begins to add complexity and scale immediately sees a need for redux like state management... (are there any large scale react apps that do not implement redux or similar?) why doesn't the react team resolve such an obvious need? its almost like its being avoided. Looking forward to hearing your answers on this one.

Comment: You mean [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)? Also, I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong, but Redux was created by React devs. I think it's more about what belongs in the react library and less of them avoiding the task

Comment: Agree with @BrianThompson here, React is a view rendering library not a complete framework like Angular. Therefore you're free to use Redux, mobx, or whatever else you like. There is, in my opinion, no obvious need to integrate state management in React itself. Context and hooks work for smaller apps. I actually think it's great that the library focuses on one thing only and does it well.

Comment: Voted to close as opinion-based and off-topic. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is for help solving specific, "hard" coding problems (as in problems involving actual code you've written).

Comment: There are many larger apps that just use Context instead of Redux or some other lib. The ```useReducer``` hook + stable ```Context``` API is basically Redux, & we get it out of the box now. It's easy to mix and match it with other forms of global state management that React gives you like ```useState``` + ```useContext```, etc. Given the current state of React (no pun intended :-D), there is no real need for Redux unless you are using a lot of 3rd party libs built on top of it.